# Column count doesn't match value count

Tags: mysql

I have a applications table with many columns 50 or more, also I've a archive table for this applications.

Now I want to restore from archive table to main table, but their column count does not match each other, so running the query:

```
INSERT INTO apps 
SELECT * FROM apps_archive
WHERE client_id = 1234
```

gives me an error:

> Error Code: 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I've tried to use `IGNORE` statement but it only works when unique key may be problem.

Things that can help me, is to run this query anyway only on matching columns, or to make archive table match the main table structure.

Thanks

Comment: I can't think of any other choice, but to make sure that their columns are matched. Unless you show us the schema difference between those 2 tables, I can't help :(

Comment: Yes I understand, they have some different fields for the purpose, archived table has some additional fields

Comment: I bet there is no easy solution, you'll have to specify all the 50+ columns, until you burn yourself typing them haha! Just copy-paste the column names from the `INSERT` statement to the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Yes I did so thanks <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the column count doesn't match, that means they two tables don't have the same table schema. If your `apps` table happens to have a lesser number of columns, then do a projection on the result from the `apps_archive` table. Otherwise, you can use a data integration tool like [Talend Open Studios for data integration](https://www.talend.com/products/talend-open-studio) to do the migration of your data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wanted to know if there was an easy solution, but as I see there is not one.